# splitting array columns

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

table1:

| rf_1 | rf_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ['abc','a'] | ['abce','cde'] |
| ['abc','cde'] | ['1','2'] |

How can I split all columns start with rf into individual columns?

Final output should look like this:

| rf_1a | rf_1b | rf_2a | rf_2b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'abc' | 'a' | 'abcde' | 'cde' |
| 'abc' | 'cde' | 1 | 2 |

Comment: see [`getItem()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html#pyspark-sql-column-getitem) column method that can extract array elements by position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below example in Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, IntegerType
dilip_sample_data  = [("['abc','a']", "['abce','cde']"),
        ("['abc','cde']", "['1','2']")]
initial_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["rf_1", "rf_2"])
def extract_elements(s):
    s = s.strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(",")
    result = []
    for x in s:
        if x.isdigit():
            result.append(int(x))
        else:
            result.append(f"'{x}'")
    return result
extract_elements_udf = udf(extract_elements, ArrayType(StringType()))
dilip_final_df = df.withColumn("rf_1a", extract_elements_udf("rf_1")[0]) \
      .withColumn("rf_1b", extract_elements_udf("rf_1")[1]) \
      .withColumn("rf_2a", extract_elements_udf("rf_2")[0]) \
      .withColumn("rf_2b", extract_elements_udf("rf_2")[1])
dilip_final_df.select("rf_1a", "rf_1b", "rf_2a", "rf_2b").show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----+-----+------+-----+
|rf_1a|rf_1b|rf_2a |rf_2b|
+-----+-----+------+-----+
|'abc'|'a'  |'abce'|'cde'|
|'abc'|'cde'|1     |2    |
+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

- I am defining sample data and creating an initial DataFrame
- Defining    a function to extract elements from a string
- Creating a user-defined    function `(UDF)` from the extract_elements function
- Applying the    `UDF` to the DataFrame to create new columns

Answer (score 0):

use `getItem()` to extract array elements.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rf1a', func.col('rf1').getItem(0)). \
    withColumn('rf1b', func.col('rf1').getItem(1)). \
    withColumn('rf2a', func.col('rf2').getItem(0)). \
    withColumn('rf2b', func.col('rf2').getItem(1)). \
    show()

# +----------+-----------+----+----+----+----+
# |       rf1|        rf2|rf1a|rf1b|rf2a|rf2b|
# +----------+-----------+----+----+----+----+
# |  [abc, a]|[abce, cde]| abc|   a|abce| cde|
# |[abc, cde]|     [1, 2]| abc| cde|   1|   2|
# +----------+-----------+----+----+----+----+
```